# Difference between match vs wild card query

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the difference between the Match and Wild card query? If the requirement is to search a combination of words in a paragraph or log which approach is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) is used to find all those documents that have the exact search term (ignore the case), whereas [Wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) returns the documents that contain the search term.

Adding a working example

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "name":"breadsticks with soup"
}
{
    "name":"multi grain bread"
}
```

**Search Query using Match query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "bread"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result will be**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67706115",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.9808291,
        "_source": {
          "name": "multi grain bread"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**Search Query using wildcard query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "name": "*bread*"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result will be**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67706115",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "multi grain bread"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67706115",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "breadsticks with soup"
        }
      }
    ]
```